# Dependencies and DLL in Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I am using VS2010's **Visual Studio Installer** to deploy my application to an **MSI**.

I referenced numerous DLLs during development; some are 3rd parties, while some are system DLLs. Now during deployment, I do not know what to include or exclude. Visual Studio automatically included **Detected Dependencies** after I added the output .EXE but they are usually not sufficient to run the application. I often had to manually include the development's DLLs to the installed application folder.  Otherwise, **eventvwr** would just provides a generic **CLR20r3** error that only tells me missing DLLs but not indicating which one.

It became a habit (a very bad habit, IMO) to include ALL references in my deployment project as they are referenced in my development project, but I guess uninstallation of the application may possibly remove System DLLs that causes problems to other application.

So how would I know which DLLs to include manually in the deployment project, in addition to the **Detected Dependencies**?

Comment: What kind of `development dll` are you talking about? I suppose that you are not talking about NET Framework dll because they should be installed by the Framework setup on your target machine.

Comment: I have multiple DLLs, such as DevExpress, some 3rd Graphics Libraries, Licensing Dlls etc. So I tried to make my question more generic..

Comment: you should include all those third party dlls, without which your application cannot run. viz, if you have used Sql Server CE, include the dll from program files >>microsoft sql server ce folder. I don't think there is any generic rule for this. make the setup, run it on a clean machine(with just dot net framework), and one by one shoot the missing dlls, once done, keep the list with you :)

Comment: that's alot of work.. so I should keep track of what DLLs to include as the development builds up ..

Comment: It is an initial step, but then this should not be a problem because adding a new libraries to your development effort is not (and should not be) a minor fact in your development history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your thirdy party dlls need to be distributed with your application.
You need to check the documentation of these libraries to get a precise answer.

As a rule of thumb, look at the References section of your projects.
Note down the libraries used there and then check with the documentation if additional libraries, not detected by VS, are needed. Sometime these libraries provides a 'Redistributable Package' that you can include in your setup project.

I prefer to do this work manually and always test in a empty virtual machine. It is very embarrassing to have a failed setup when your customers install the application.

To deinstall, you really have nothing to worry if you install everything in your application folder.

Comment: You are correct, but I've discovered that 'detected dependencies' can magically re-add things including excluded files! See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1900756